# Why mongod said "note: noprealloc may hurt performance in many applications"?

Tags: mongodb, configuration

I just start mongod with config file:

```
mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

In /etc/mongod.conf, I set storage.preallocDataFiles=true

This is a part of config:

```
storage:
   dbPath: "/data/db"
   directoryPerDB: true
   indexBuildRetry: true
   preallocDataFiles: true
   nsSize: 16
```

Why mongod tell me "note: noprealloc may hurt performance in many applications" ?

Comment: It is possible a bug of mongo 2.6.6 because it disappear when I remove preallocDataFiles: true in config file (preallocDataFiles is always true by default)

Comment: I thought we had caught all of these (setting a default causing it to flip).  Let me see if I can reproduce and I'll file a ticket if so

Comment: Question for you - what OS and filesystem were you using? I just tried this on Linux with 2.6.6 on ext4 and was unable to reproduce

Comment: I am using Centos 6.5 and filesystem type is ext4. I also using LVM. Mongodb version is 2.6.6 Linux kernel is 2.6.32. I hope my information I provided will be useful.

Comment: Its on mongo source code: mongod_options.cpp , What happens if you start mongo with arguments rather than config file?       
 if (params.count("storage.mmapv1.preallocDataFiles")) {
mmapv1GlobalOptions.prealloc = params["storage.mmapv1.preallocDataFiles"].as<bool>();
cout << "note: noprealloc may hurt performance in many applications" << endl;
}